# Equivalence relations and bijections without ordered pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Is it correct that — opposed to general relations and functions — *equivalence* relations and *bijective* functions can be defined without reference to ordered pairs? Especially, do the following definitions capture the usual notions of equivalence and bijection?

> **Definition**: $X$ is an ***equivalence relation*** on set $Y$ if
>
> 1. $X \subset \mathcal{P}(Y)$
> 2. $(\forall x \in X)\ |x| = 1 \vee |x| = 2$
> 3. $(\forall y \in Y)\ \lbrace y \rbrace \in X$
> 4. $(\forall x,y,z \in Y)\ \lbrace x,y \rbrace \in X \wedge \lbrace y,z \rbrace \in X \rightarrow \lbrace x,z \rbrace \in X$
>
> **Definition**: $X$ is a ***bijection*** between sets $Y$ and $Z$ if
>
> 1. $(\forall x \in X)(\exists y \in Y)(\exists z \in Z)\ \lbrace y,z\rbrace = x$
> 2. $(\forall y \in Y)(\forall z \in Z)(\exists x \in X)\ \lbrace y,z\rbrace = x$

Or is there a mistake in one of these definitions?

Comment: Your definition of bijection is incorrect as stated: part 2 requires that for *every* $y\in Y$ and *every* $z\in Z$ you have $\{y,z\}\in X$. You are just saying that $X$ is the collection of *all* subsets that contains exactly one element from $Y$ and one element from $Z$ (possibly the same element). So, for example, the only set that satisfies your definition of "bijection" with $Y=\{a,b\}$ and $Z=\{a,1,2\}$ is $X=\{ \{a\}, \{a,1\}, \{a,2\}, \{a,b\}, \{b,1\}, \{b,2\}\}$. This satisfies your definition, and is not what you really want to call a "bijection", is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "equivalence" definition looks okay (and the same technique can encode every symmetric relation), but the "bijection" one has trouble.

It can only begin to work if $Y$ and $Z$ are *disjoint*. And even so, the second condition must be replaced with two:

- $(\forall y \in Y)(\exists_1 z \in Z)\ \lbrace y,z\rbrace \in X$
- $(\forall z \in Z)(\exists_1 y \in Y)\ \lbrace y,z\rbrace \in X$

where $\exists_1$ is the "there exists exactly one" quantifier.

Comment: Together with Arturo's comment I understand that my definition is flawn and yours is much better and appropriate. But why do $Y$ and $Z$ have to be disjoing?

Comment: Otherwise you don't know, when you see $\{a,b\}$ and $a$ and $b$ are both in $X\cap Y$ whether $a$ maps to $b$ or vice versa. For example there is a bijection $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ that adds 1 to every number, and a different bijection that subtracts 1 from every number. But your scheme would attempt to represent both as $\{\{0,1\},\{0,-1\},\{1,2\},\{-1,-2\},\{2,3\},\ldots\}$.

Comment: So I should not call it "bijection" or "bijective function". Could you propose something if I would like to capture only the concept of "being equipollent"?

Comment: I don't think trying to patch it up will give you anything that is simpler than the usual ordered-pair based definition. For example, you'll want to have a witness for $\mathbb N\simeq\mathbb Z$, and for that you need to have some natural numbers map to negatives and themselves be images of _other_ naturals. Getting the bookkeeping right there will require you to invent something that is essentially as strong as ordered pairs.

Comment: I'm not looking for something *simpler* but for something more *natural* and less *ambiguous* than any specific definition of "ordered pair" (like Kuratowski's). Especially I try to define "equipollent" without ordered pairs.

Comment: I still think the best thing you can hope for is to replace Kuratowski pairs with "Stricker pairs" of an equally arbitrary anatomy.

Comment: Sounds bad (for my intention).

Answer (score 5):

Every equivalence relation on a set $X$ defines a (unique) partition on said set, so you can conversely define an equivalence relation using not ordered pairs, but partitions.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that a bijection is, in particular, a *function*, and therefore must have a specified domain and codomain. How would you define the inverse of a bijection in your definition?

In other words, *your bijections are not in bijection with my bijections*, because for any such set $X$ in your definition, there are two bijections in my definition, namely, $f_X:Y\to Z$ and $f_X^{-1}:Z\to Y$.